# What is "hitting the ground too hard?" in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I noticed that some people get killed in Minecraft because they "hit the ground too hard", but what is the difference between it and "fell too high"?

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Death_messages

Comment: @Joachim "difference with" sounds wrong.

Comment: @Stormblessed Something can differ from something, or be different from something, but 'difference from' is wrong (see, for example, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36756/difference-to-or-difference-with-or-difference-from)).

Answer (score 5):

"Hit the ground too hard" is the death message used when a player is killed by a fall less than 5 blocks, ender pearl damage, or by falling while riding an entity that died due to fall damage (e.g., if the player rides a pig off a cliff and dies). "Fell too high" is used when a player is killed by a fall greater than 5 blocks. [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Death_messages)